# Return a default value in SQL even if the query return no result

Tags: sql, case, between, nvl

For a very specific need for my application, in the best scenario, **I must always retrieve an additional record preceding the date filter that the user selected.**

Suppose in my database I have orders with the following dates ('20220701', '20221231', '20230101', '20230701', '20240101') and the user wants all orders from 2023 (*keeping in mind that I need an additional previous record*).

On-screen user date filter... From: "20230101"    To: "20231231"

Currently I am using the following query:

```
SELECT Ord1.OrderDate FROM Orders Ord1
WHERE Ord1.OrderDate BETWEEN (SELECT MAX(Ord2.OrderDate)
FROM Orders Ord2 WHERE Ord2.OrderDate < '20230101')
AND '20231231'
ORDER BY Ord1.OrderDate
```

Running the query I get: ('20221231', '20230101', '20230701') witch is perfect!!!

My problem is that let's assume that the user **DID NOT** place any order in 2022, so my database contains ('20230101', '20230701', '20240101'), at this point my query no longer works, because I do not "*respect*" the first condition in my *BETWEEN* clause, but I must still have the result ('20230101', '20230701').

Comment: If you want the oldest date, then why are you selecting MAX()?

Comment: @Isolated OP wants the MAX date prior to 20240101 if there is one, otherwise the MIN date after that.

Comment: @Kurt I edited my question to be more specific with what exactly I want to do

Comment: @pgendron it makes no sense to me now.  the user has asked for records between two dates, and you want to show them a record prior to that range even when there isn't one?

Comment: @pgendron why doesn't `BETWEEN '20230101' AND '20231231'` work for you?

Comment: @Kurt It's obvious that outside the context of my application, it's difficult to understand what I want to do, especially since in my example, I used order dates to simplify understanding (but I think that I've done worse and it's true that it doesn't make any sense). In real context, I want to calculate the distance traveled by a vehicle between 2 dates for which there are several fuel entry recorded with an odometer for each one. However, to calculate the distance for the first entry, I have to rely on the odometer of the previous record, which is why I have to retrieve an additional row.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is some kind of NVL function over subqueries, like this:

```
SELECT NVL(
    (SELECT MAX(Date) FROM Table1 WHERE Date < '20240101'),
    (SELECT MIN(Date) FROM Table1)
) d
```

That way, if the first subquery returns NULL, the outer query will return the result of the second subquery.

The exact syntax will depend on your DBMS.  For example, in Oracle you would need "FROM DUAL" for it to be valid.  COALESCE() might work if your DBMS doesn't have NVL()

Comment: Or conditional aggregation. `SELECT COALESCE( MAX(CASE WHEN Date < '20240101' THEN Date END),MIN(Date)) FROM Table1 `

Comment: @MartinSmith There might be an optimization to return the original date rather than actually searching for the minimum. The flip side is that you then have to repeat the same date value of course.

Answer (score 2):

This could be accomplished with a union:

```
SELECT OrderDate
FROM Orders
WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN '20230101' AND '20231231'
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(OrderDate)
FROM Orders
WHERE OrderDate < '20230101'
ORDER BY Ord1.OrderDate;
```

The minor downside is having to repeat the date but you might find this performs better.

Answer (score 1):

One of the many universal ways to solve your problem. The solution returns values from all columns of the `orders` table, not just the values of the `orderdate` column.
But if you had told us which DBMS you were using, the solutions would have been more optimal.

```
select
  *
from orders
where
  orderdate in (
    select max(orderdate)
    from orders
    where orderdate >= '20220101'
      and orderdate < '20230101'
    union all
    select orderdate
    from orders
    where orderdate >= '20230101'
      and orderdate < '20240101'
  );
```

Try it on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Yp8kYKxp).

Answer (score 0):

With all your help, here is how I resolve it:

```
SELECT T1.OrderDate
FROM Orders T1
WHERE T1.OrderDate BETWEEN
    COALESCE((SELECT MAX(T2.OrderDate)
    FROM Orders T2 WHERE
    T2.OrderDate < '20230101'), '20230101')
AND '20231231'
```

Comment: I feel I should caution you to be careful and test thoroughly. This query does not seem to care about a "user's" orders - as you mention in your question description. It is really just about "all orders" or "any order" ... it will give the same result every time doesn't matter who the "user" is...

Comment: @topsail you are absolutely right, I shortened the query to get straight to the point